# How to parse char str and create a new array of ints

Tags: c

I want to fill an array with int values which are extracted from a buffer. I want to do something like:

```
char buffer[BUFF_MAX];
int numbers[NUM_MAX];
int i = 0;    

fgets(buffer, BUFF_MAX, stdin);
while(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &numbers[i]) == 1)
{
    ++i;
}
```

but I am having all kinds of problems using this method. Perhaps it has something to do with the \n in the buffer? It seems like the same value is assigned to every element and if I type in anything greater than around 130, a garbage value is stored.

The user will be typing in something like:

```
12 543 5 234 9
```

and I want these values to be stored in `numbers[]` as 5 different elements. There will be different amounts of numbers in the buffer each time (depending on what the user types in).

Comment: You are only reading one single line. Is that intentional?

Comment: `numbers` is declared a `char` array, not an `int` array.

Comment: Yes, I was going to run this snippet in a for loop. The user would specify how many lines they want to create and the loop would adjust accordingly. I am actually creating a 2d array, each line would be a row in the 2d array, but I figured this wasn't relevant to my question and the above was a simpler version of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out where `sscanf()` got to in parsing the string by using the `%n` conversion specifier, thus:

```
char buffer[BUFF_MAX];
int numbers[NUM_MAX];
int i = 0;
int offset = 0;
int newlen;

if (fgets(buffer, BUFF_MAX, stdin) != 0)
{
    while (sscanf(buffer + offset, "%d%n", &numbers[i], &newlen) == 1 && i < NUM_MAX)
    {
        ++i;
        offset += newlen;
    }
}
```

---

#### Testing

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum { BUFF_MAX = 1024, NUM_MAX = 32 };

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFF_MAX];
    int numbers[NUM_MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int newlen;

    if (fgets(buffer, BUFF_MAX, stdin) != 0)
    {
        while (sscanf(buffer + offset, "%d%n", &numbers[i], &newlen) == 1 && i < NUM_MAX)
        {
            printf("Found: numbers[%d] = %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
            ++i;
            offset += newlen;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input string:

```
123 456 789 0123456
```

Output:

```
Found: numbers[0] = 123
Found: numbers[1] = 456
Found: numbers[2] = 789
Found: numbers[3] = 123456
```

The `%n` modifier was added in C89, but not many people know that it is there.  It also 'works' in the `printf()` family of functions, but is even more lethal there because people aren't used to seeing output parameters in a `printf()` format string.  At least with `scanf()` et al, you are expecting inputs.

Beware of 'format string vulnerabilities', a decent search term to use in your favourite search engine.  You should be beware of them, independently of this question.

[*Updated to check that `fgets()` does not indicate an error or EOF.  Always check that read operations do what you expected.  Well, almost always — if you're recovering from an error and don't care what is read because you won't be using it, maybe you don't need to check.  If you're going to use the read data, you should check that you actually got the data to work with.*]

Answer (score 1):

sscanf has a limitation in that it doesn't tell you how long the data was. I'd use a solution found in `string.h`, namely strtol.

```
char buffer[BUFF_MAX];
int numbers[NUM_MAX];
char* seek, *seekp;
seek = seekp = buffer;
int i = 0;    

fgets(buffer, BUFF_MAX, stdin);
while( 1 == 1)
{
    numbers[i] = strtol(seek, &seek, 10);
    if( seekp == seek || i >= NUM_MAX )
        break;
    seekp = seek;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: >char* seek, seekp;
Will this not declare seekp as a char, and seek as a char*? Avoid declaring multiple pointer variables on a single line to avoid such problems.

Comment: Note that `sscanf()` has the `%n` format specifier precisely to tell you where in the string it got to.

Comment: I missed a star there, Pod. Jonathan, I never knew that. That's a very nice trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You are always scanning from the beginning of the buffer - you need the next sscanf to begin where the previous one ended.

Why do you fgets into a buffer and then sscanf? You could scanf an int at a time directly from stdin. It is easier because when you read from stdin the input is consumed so you don't need to worry about it repeating.

Comment: It is generally easier to manage error reporting using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` than using just `scanf()`.  You can also react to users typing empty lines in frustration, whereas `scanf()` blithely ignores the empty lines and goes on waiting for something, anything, that is not white space.